# How to navigate between View with Prism 7.2?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism-7

I'm writing an application and I want to put navigation in it. This application is using WPF and I'm using Prism 7.2.0.1367.

So I created 2 views: a `HomePage` and a `ModeFileAttente` view.

I'm also using the MVVM pattern.

Here is my `app.xaml.cs` :

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<V.HomePage>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    { 
        containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<V.HomePage, VM.HomePageViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<V.ModeFileAttente, VM.ModeFIleAttenteViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog  moduleCatalog)
    {
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<Bootstrapper>();
    }
}
```

My `HomePage.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.View.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="HomePage" Height="347.667" Width="664">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="277*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0.333,-0.333">
        <Button Padding="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Mode normal" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="ModeFileAttente"/>
        <Button Padding="0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Mode tournois" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" Margin="5"  />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the view model:

```
class HomePageViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware, INotifyPropertyChanged
{   

    #region Private region
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;
    #endregion

    public DelegateCommand<string> ClickCommand { get; private set; }



    public string Title => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public HomePageViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteClickCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteClickCommand(string path) {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "FileAttente");
    }

    public bool CanCloseDialog()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDialogClosed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I also got a `Bootstrapper` class :

```
public class Bootstrapper : IModule
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ModeFileAttente>();
    }
}
```

My MVVM pattern work's well, but when I want to navigate between my "HomePage" and my "ModeFileAttente" view, nothing happens except a "System.Object" on my view.

I already search what could be the problem, but I didn't something that resolve my issue.

Did someone still got this error with this version of prism ?

PS: my 2 view are in a "View" folder, same for the view model in a ViewModel folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should register view with region on initialize. try the below code

```
public class Bootstrapper : IModule
{
     public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
     {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionName", typeof(View));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RegionName", typeof(View2));
     }
}
```

Now you can use

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("RegionName", "View");
```

Or

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("RegionName", "View2");
```

**Update**

If we use prism then there should be a dependency injection framework associated to it for example `MEF` or `Unity`for my project I am using `Prism.Unity.Wpf` if you are using `Unity` then you can ask your dependency injector to inject RegionManager by adding a constructor which will be injected by a `IRegionManager` see below

```
    readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public Bootstrapper(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }
```

When you Inject `IRegionManager` to the constructor `Unity` know to provide same instance all the time as it is maintained in `Unity` so no need to worry about using the same instance of `IRegionManager` elsewhere.

when we use `prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"` in XAML we are actually keeping a place holder to say `Prism` that there is a region which will be filled by any `VIEW` at some point look for it.

This is my understanding. Let me know if you find this useful Thanks.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. How can I can initialise a `RegionManager` in my `Bootstrapper` and use the same instance in my different ViewModel ? Moreover, this line `<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" Margin="5"  />` is not supposed to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

"FileAttente" should be "ModeFileAttente":

```
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ModeFileAttente");
```

There is no "FileAttente" view registered for navigation.

Comment: What does can't navigate" mean? Don't you see the `ModeFileAttenteView` in the `ContentControl`?

Comment: I mean, when I click on my button, It does nothing, I'm still on my `HomePage` view